# Amazon Chime SDK | SQS notiification detailed analysis

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-nodejs, aws-chime-sdk, amazon-chime

I've successfully configured [notifications](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/chime/latest/dg/mtgs-sdk-notifications.html) for AWS Chime meetings (meetings are handled with SDK).

Main goal behind configuring notifications(SQS) is to keep track of all the meetings those are created and how many participants are joined.

Is there any solution provided by Amazon Chime to save these records/events into table (e.g. dynamodb) and receive analytics on meetings those are created with [SDK](https://github.com/aws/amazon-chime-sdk-js)

In other words, I need analytics or detailed report for meetings which are handled by [amazon-chime-sdk-js](https://github.com/aws/amazon-chime-sdk-js)

Any kind of information or help would be appreciated on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As I know AWS doesn't provide any solution for that case. For a similar purpose, I configured a lambda that process all messages from SQS and put it into my DB. It works fine

Comment: Can you explain your workaround in detail, I am doing work on it. I want to save all the chat messages in the meeting to save in DB also what about mobile chat in AWS Chime SDK if you know about it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to track meetings and store for billing or analytics, best way is to do it via AWS EventBridge. It is very simple to enable and has all events such as when did meeting get started, ended, #of participants, duration and so on.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/chime/latest/ag/automating-chime-with-cloudwatch-events.html

We built handlers to take these events from EventBridge and use that for analytics.